# sql INNER JOIN on update query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys i was trying to convert my `INSERT` query into an `Update` query. But i have problems doing it. This is my `Insert` query:

```
INSERT INTO lm_Artikel (Status)
SELECT 'NOK' 
FROM lm_Artikel A 
INNER JOIN lm_Schwellwert S ON A.Typ = S.Typ  
WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```

And this is my attemp to convert it:

```
Update A SET A.Status = 'NOK'
FROM lm_Artikel A
INNER JOIN  lm_Schwellwert S ON A.Typ = S.Typ  
WHERE A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```

It is not working can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in MySQL, there is no `FROM` keyword when joining a table. Your join syntax is correct but that's for `T-SQL`

```
Update  lm_Artikel A 
        INNER JOIN  lm_Schwellwert S 
            ON A.Typ = S.Typ  
SET     A.Status = 'NOK'
WHERE   A.Bestand < S.Schwellwert
```

- [UPDATE with JOIN](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)